# Ruby on Rails (CKeditor - Magic-line) : After reloading page magic-line is not appearing in CKeditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

In my Ruby On Rails application, I have CKEditor  in that **`CKEditor magic-line` is there, after reloading**  only i am able to get that magic-line. without reloading if i switched other element CKEditor i am not able to do get magic line in current_element CKEditor.

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: have you refer this http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/magicline.html for magic-ine